# launching clementine after 14.04 install

Tags: clementine

When I tried to launch the first time after upgrading, it said `Clementine unexpectedly stopped`

Since then, no error notices, just failed launching. I have restarted it a few times. I really need my play-lists.

Your help is much appreciated, this is exactly what I feared might happen if I upgraded!

Comment: Could you attach to your question the error messages of running clementine from a terminal? just type `clementine`